# Scanf specific Characters into array in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am currently taking a basic C course and I was wondering why my code below doesn't run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    char string[4];

    printf("Enter some text\n");
    scanf(" %c %c %c", &string[0], &string[1], &string[2]);

    printf("You Entered ");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c",string[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Xcode said there is an errr with my scanf line.

I was hoping to type in "a b c d" and expect 
a "You entered abcd";

Comment: What error did it say specifically?

Comment: "(lldb)"
"error: 'apropos' must be called with exactly one argument."

Comment: Did you type `make` or `man` to build?

Comment: Based on that error, why do you think the problem is with the scanf line?

Comment: I used Xcode to go to Product>Run if that helps. Also, I not sure what that error is saying, especially the apropos part.

Comment: Have you tried putting the 'int i' line below 'char string[4]'.  Variable declarations need to be at the start of a block in plain C.

Comment: `lldb` refers to the debugger.  `apropos` is one of the commands for retrieving help information while debugging.  Perhaps the debugger configuration is off?

Comment: I strongly recommend learning how to compile with the command-line tools. It adds to the learning curve, but it can be an essential skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should run (albeit with a bug). I suspect you need to configure the Xcode build options correctly.

As for the bug, you have an array of four chars, but you are only scanning for three. Add another `%c` and `&string[3]` to your `scanf` line.

Here's an [ideone](https://ideone.com/3oia5e) snippet showing the modified code in action

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    char string[4];
    int i;

    printf("Enter some text\n");
    scanf("%c %c %c %c", &string[0], &string[1], &string[2], &string[3]);

    printf("You Entered ");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c", string[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles just fine on the Mac command line (assuming the source is in "test.c")

```
$ cc -g -Wall -o test test.c 
./test
Enter some text
a b c d
You Entered abcd
```

Also note that this particular snippet requires only `stdio.h` (`man scanf` and `man printf` will tell you which header to use).

Answer (score 0):

How about executing this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    char strin[10];

    printf("Enter some text\n");
    scanf("%s", strin);

    printf("You Entered %s",strin);

    return 0;
}
```

The following code gives you :

```
Enter some text
abcd
You Entered abcd
```

[image]